# Dom performance

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, event-delegation

I am building a to-do app which is a CRUD intensive application. the HTML for the user tasks looks similar to this

```
<ul class="tasks-wrapper">
  <li class="task-item" data-id=1>Task_1</li>
  <li class="task-item" data-id=2>Task_2</li>
</ul>
```

Basically, a click on any `li` item means that the user wants to update the content of the task, `li` item. One way to implement that functionality is by doing the following

```
all_tasks = document.querySelectorAll('li.task-item');
all_tasks.forEach((task) => {
task.onclick = fire_callback_function_to_update_content_of_selected_task;
});
```

The above code works fine, but I can’t identify whether it is performance friendly or not. My question is when does the loop get executed? does it get executed every time the dom triggers an event on the page or only when it triggers an event on tasks-wrapper?

Currently, I have changed my implementation using event-delegation on my tasks-wrapper element which gives better performance, but still, I want to understand the performance of the previous solution and if anyone has a better performance-friendly implementation in mind.

```
tasks = document.querySelector('ul.tasks-wrapper');
tasks .addEventListener('click', respondToTheClick);
function respondToTheClick (event){
  If (event.target && event.target.match('li.task-item')){
   // callfunction to update content of selected task using its id which you can get using
  event.target.id
  }
}
```

Comment: *My question is when does the loop get executed?* It depends on where you've placed that code.

Comment: Globally in my JS file. I do believe that when the JS code runs for the first time, n (number of li items) event handlers are going to be stored in the execution call stack waiting to be fired, but I am not sure.

Comment: The performance feature of chrome dev tools would probably help here. Does this video help answer the question? https://youtu.be/TtsvMRxmfGA?t=1325

Comment: You need to be more specific than *globally*.  Please show where you have that code in the larger scheme of things so we can know at what point it executes.